# PIVOT - Dificuldade com as Colunas

Tags: sql-server

Considerando a tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VENDAS](
    [VENCIMENTO] [datetime] NULL,
    [VENCIDO] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [RECEBIDO] [decimal](18, 0) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO VENDAS VALUES('2019-01-10', 50, 49,80)
INSERT INTO VENDAS VALUES('2019-02-10', 50, 49.80)
INSERT INTO VENDAS VALUES('2019-03-10', 50, 49,80)
```

Como chegar nesse resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei montar um resultado mas sem sucesso.
Utilizei esta consulta:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT VENCIDO, RECEBIDO, VENCIMENTO
          FROM VENDAS) AS V
PIVOT (SUM(V.RECEBIDO) FOR V.RECEBIDO IN ([0])) AS PV1
```

No caso preciso que os registros de Vencimento se transformem em colunas.

Comment: Isso não é pivô mas sim transposição de matriz. Uma solução é montar 3 SELECT, um para cada linha do resultado, e reuni-los com UNION ALL.

Comment: Sugestão de leitura: https://gustavomaiaaguiar.wordpress.com/2009/07/13/pivoteando-despivoteando-transpondo-invertendo-colunas-e-linhas-no-sql-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando o `UNION ALL` do nosso amigo, acredito que pode dar certo.

```
    SELECT  
         TIPO,
         [2019/01/10],
         [2019/02/10]
         [2019/03/10]
     FROM 
    (select 
          'VL_VENCIDO'as  TIPO,
           VENCIDO as  VALOR 
       from OPERACAO
    UNION ALL
    select 
          'VL_RECEBIDO'as  TIPO,
           RECEBIDO as  VALOR 
       from OPERACAO
     )AS TAB1

     PIVOT (SUM(vencido)
       FOR VENCIMENTO
        IN ( [2019/01/10],[2019/02/10],[2019/03/10])  
     ) P
```

Aqui eu acabei criando uma tabela inserindo a descrição `VENCIDO` e `RECEBIDO` e seus valores como `DADOS`.

**Ai deu certo na estrutura abaixo:**

```
SELECT CD,
       TIPO,
       [2019/05/01],
       [2019/05/02],
       [2019/05/03]
  FROM 

 ( SELECT tmp.cd,
          tmp.dt,
          TMPTIPO.TIPO,
          TMPTIPO.VALOR

     FROM TMP
     JOIN TMPTIPO ON tmp.cd_f = TMPTIPO.CD
               AND tmp.dt   = TMPTIPO.DT   
    WHERE tmp.dt BETWEEN '2019/05/01' AND '2019/05/30'
      AND TMP.cd=1

  ) AS S
  PIVOT (SUM(VALOR)
     FOR DT
      IN ( [2019/05/01],
           [2019/05/02],
           [2019/05/03])  
         ) P
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. vlw.